# How to fully reinstall lamp stack on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I've run into problems with my lamp stack on 16.04.

Could not login into mysql using:

`mysql -u root`

tried to execute `mysql_secure_installation`, and tried to change password after login into mysql using

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

After several attempts and instructions I run into a statement, when I can't even login into mysql using sudo.

So I would like to start over (like after fresh installation) and try to install lamp stack. How can I do that now?